# How to use memcached? Criteria is if the name of user is updated then that name has to be updated in memcached.How to create memcached & updated it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached

** This is my UserController",for user views I am using only new.html.erb which consists of a user form that's it .How to write apply memcached for this do I create new file or do I need to write a code in user.rb file**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    @users=User.all 
    render :json=> @users
  end
  def new
  end
  def create
    name = params[:name]
    email = params[:email]
    password = params[:password]
    role = params[:role]
    new_user = User.new(
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      role: role,
    )
    new_user.save
    if new_user.save
      
      session[:current_user_id] = new_user.id
      session[:current_user_role] = new_user.role
      @user=new_user
     
      redirect_to "/"
    else
      
      redirect_to new_user_path
    end
  end
  
end
```

Comment: Probably fine to put the code in your controller. If you want to have magic you can have a trigger in the model instead. I used internet to find [dalli](https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli) that seems to be the most popular memcached client for ruby.

Comment: @froderik I didn't get how to write a code? I am new to rubyonrails could you please provide the code using memcached.It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: What are you using memcached for. As a cache? Then why only cache the name and not the entire user? Here is [an article](https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli/wiki/Using-Dalli-with-Rails) about using dalli with rails. Duckduckgo is your friend.